# SQL Server: store INT in BIGINT column can be a problem?

Tags: sql-server, function, types

I have mapping table in the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE MappingTable 
(
    TableName SYSNAME,
    SrcId BIGINT,
    DstId BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Name, SrcId),
    UNIQUE (Name, DstId)
)
```

`SrcId` and `DstId` are referring to `Identity` columns in 2 identical databases, most of the columns type is `INT` but some are `BIGINT`, therefore I am storing all as `BIGINT`.

Now I want to write function to get `DstId` for `TableName` and `SrcId`.

So my question is simple: do I have any reason to implement 2 functions, one for `INT` and the 2nd for `BIGINT`?

To clarify: I read what I'd wrote: when an `INT` was written it reads as `INT`, and the same is for `BIGINT`.

Comment: @Sami thanks, I just wanted to be sure...

Comment: *"you can't do the opposite."* isn't quite true. You can assign the value of a `bigint` to an `int`, provided the value of the `bigint` doesn't exceed the maximum/minimum value of an `int`. For example. `DECLARE @bi bigint = 1, @i int; SET @i = @bi;` will run fine.

Comment: BigInt use twice as much storage as int, but since storage is so cheap these days, I don't see a reason to have two mappings tables instead of one here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have any reason to implement 2 Functions, one for INT and the 2nd for BIGINT?

The simple answer to this No, you need just one function for `BIGINT`,
eg:

```
DECLARE @BigInt BIGINT = 922337203685477580;
DECLARE @Int INT = 2147483647;

--SET @Int = @BigInt; this wont work, so your choice is BIGINT
SET @BigInt = @Int;
```

and here is a **[`test`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a3ce450a16807ffea9938e59452c8f5)** with functions to make it very clear.

---

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| Data type |                                  Range                                   | Storage |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| bigint    | -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) | 8 Bytes |
| int       | -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)                         | 4 Bytes |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

See **[`int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**